# VS Code - Completion is terrible, is it my setup?

Tags: intellisense, visual-studio-code

Code completion and intellisense in VS Code is absolutely god-awful for me. In every language. I have extensions installed and updated but its always absolute trash.

```
import pandas as pd
data_all = pd.read_csv(DATA_FILE, header=None)
data_all. (press tab)
```

No suggestions.

Do you really not know its a Pandas DataFrame object, its literally the line above?

I have this issue in python, in ruby/rails, pretty much every langauge i try to use the completion is absolute garbage. Do i have an extension that is breaking other extensions? is code jsut this bad? Why is it so inexplicably useless?

Installed Currently:

abusaidm.html-s

```
nippets@0.2.1  
alefragnani.numbered-bookmarks@8.0.2  
bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client@1.6.3  
bung87.rails@0.16.11  
bung87.vscode-gemfile@0.4.0  
castwide.solargraph@0.21.1  
CoenraadS.bracket-pair-colorizer@1.0.61  
donjayamanne.python-extension-pack@1.6.0  
ecmel.vscode-html-css@1.10.2  
felixfbecker.php-debug@1.14.9  
felixfbecker.php-intellisense@2.3.14  
felixfbecker.php-pack@1.0.2  
formulahendry.auto-close-tag@0.5.10  
golang.go@0.23.2  
groksrc.ruby@0.1.0  
k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings@1.4.0  
KevinRose.vsc-python-indent@1.12.0  
Leopotam.csharpfixformat@0.0.84  
magicstack.MagicPython@1.1.0  
miguel-savignano.ruby-symbols@0.1.8  
ms-dotnettools.csharp@1.23.9  
ms-mssql.mssql@1.10.1  
ms-python.python@2021.2.636928669  
ms-python.vscode-pylance@2021.3.1  
ms-toolsai.jupyter@2021.3.619093157  
ms-vscode.cpptools@1.2.2  
rebornix.ruby@0.28.1  
sianglim.slim@0.1.2  
VisualStudioExptTeam.vscodeintellicode@1.2.11  
wingrunr21.vscode-ruby@0.28.0  
Zignd.html-css-class-completion
```

@1.20.0

Comment: It completely depends on the extension setup. I cannot say much without having an extension list.
I've used kite auto complete engine for python https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kiteco.kite

Comment: Edited to reflect my ext list.

Comment: 1. The shortcut to trigger autocompletion is ^Space, not "(press tab)" https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features 2. VSCode only provides the infrastructure, and autocompletion list is generated by the actual language extension you use. Due to the complexity to write a good extension/language server, not all language extensions provide good results, not surprising.

Comment: Ive reset some hotkeys. but whatever you want to call it, tab, Ctrl+Space, intellisnese, etc. Other editors have VASTLY out-performed VS code in my experience. I can pick editors for python that are great, or editors for ruby that get it right, and i refuse to beleive code is so popular and so horrible at this. There must be a way to get it to work that I am just not getting.

Comment: It's not your setup. It's VS Code. Its autocomplete and auto indentation are just awful out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the IntelliSense of the `read_csv()` method (By hovering your mouse over it), you will see that it returns a `DataFrame` object

```
(function)
read_csv(reader: IO, sep: str = ...,

#Okay... very long definition but scroll to the end... 

 float_precision: str | None = ...) -> DataFrame
```

But if you use IntelliSense check the variable `data_all`

```py
import pandas as pd
data_all = pd.read_csv(DATA_FILE, header=None)
```

It is listed as the default data type in python: `Any`. That's why your compiler isn't generating the autocomplete.

So, you simply need to explicitly tell your compiler that it is, in fact, a `DataFrame` object as shown.

```py
import pandas as pd
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
DATA_FILE = "myfile"
data_all:DataFrame = pd.read_csv(DATA_FILE, header=None)
# Now all autocomplete options on data_all are available!
```

It might seem strange why the compiler cannot guess the data type in this example until you realize that the `read_csv()` method is overloaded with many definitions, and some of them return objects as `Any` type. So the compiler assumes the worst-case scenario and treats it as an `Any` type object unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Thats an option.... but thats awful design in terms of the application meant to make this easier. In my experience, other IDEs have worked to autocomplete this based on what its assigned to above, knowing the reurn.

Comment: @aescript I edited the answer just now to explain why this problem happens, but I agree this design can be a pain

Comment: I just dont understand why other editors get this right. Im torn because i can use another IDE that makes my life easy, but then i have tos witch between 12 languages im using - or I can use Code and do them all in one with god-awful support. For instance rails is the worst. Not a single call i start to type in is completed... its not even a typing issue, there is no type yet. but even with ruby and rails extensions installed, i start typing a VERY common function (redirect_to()) and its like ???? what are you doing?